# if block in javascript not running

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This if block:

```
count = 1;
if (count == 4) {
            alert(count);
            $(":checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
            count = 0;
        }
```

is not running. I have also added an alert() but its not appearing. My javascript code also contains some jQuery. How to solve it?

Comment: write `count = 4` before the posted code and make sure it reaches this line...

Comment: Maybe its not running, because ``count`` is never ``4`` ^^

Comment: Could you elaborate on where the variable `count` comes from?

Comment: In another words - show us where and how you set ``count`` value

Comment: Check the error console first. If there are no errors, try to create a jsFiddle that reproduces your problem. We certainly need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your current code, you're always setting `count` to `1` before checking whether it is `4`. It will never be `4`, it will always be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this information, it would appear that `count` is not 4. If you want this block to run anyway, get rid of the whole `if(){}` around it.